# matploblib, alpha colormap different with contourf and imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

With matplotlib (1.3.1) I define a custom colormap with a alpha layer.
Then I use the colormap with imshow and contourf and the transparency looks different.

Here is a mininal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

cdict1 = {'red':   ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),

         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

         'blue':  ((0.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
        }


cdict1['alpha'] = ((0.0, 0.5, 0.5),
                   (1.0, 0.5, 0.5))

plt.register_cmap(name='BlueRedAlpha', data=cdict1)


Z = np.zeros([10, 10])

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest',cmap="BlueRedAlpha",vmin=-100,vmax=100)


plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.contourf(Z,cmap="BlueRedAlpha",vmin=-100,vmax=100,antialiased=True)


plt.show()
```

The colors are not the same for imshow and contourf.
How can obtain the same color?

Comment: 80% your issues is that `contourf` is not filling the patches at the value you think it is.  The color is the _middle_ between the contour above and below.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this produce a level shift. But here the alpha channel is different for the complete colormap range.